# How to write to bootstrap-vue table fields with non-latin letters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to write a table in the Cyrillic alphabet, but in the program the key of the object should be only in the Latin alphabet.

**Code :**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      wmsFields: ['№', 'Наименование', 'Код', 'Баркод', 'Кол-во', 'Остаток 1С', 'Ряд', 'Стеллаж', 'Полка'],
        wms: [
          {No: '1', Naimenovanie: 'Jon doe', Kod: '13232', barkod: 'asas'...},
        ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this and then use value of the key for elements key:

Template **:**

```
<tr key="wmsField.key"></tr>
```

Script **:**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      wmsFields: [
        { key: "number", value: '№' }, 
        { key: "name", value:'Наименование' }, 
        { key: 'code', value: 'Код'}, ....],
      wms: [
        {No: '1', Naimenovanie: 'Jon doe', Kod: '13232', barkod: 'asas'...},
      ]
    }
}
```